# What are the CarbonComponentScanner and VisualizerService-x86 (Music) processes?

Tags: activity-monitor

In `Activity Monitor.app` I've wanted to find out what are the `x86`, Intel processes that I still have on my *Apple Silicon* MacBook.

The only two x86 processes are `CarbonComponentScanner` and `VisualizerService-x86 (Music)`. Does anyone know what they are and what they are doing?

[image: Activity Monitor.app showing processes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CarbonComponentScannerXPC references Rosetta and the Audio Toolbox (using "Open Files and Ports" in Activity Monitor).

The Visualiser is the freaky whoosh display in iTunes/Music that dances to the music.

In short: nothing to worry about, and unlikely to affect performance.